# filter blast output for e value

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I ran a BlastX against the SwissProt database in with an -evalue threshold of 1e-3.

The output looks like:

```
>TCONS_00006082    sp|P43298|TMK1_ARATH    57.89    57    23    2    459    292    751    806    8e-11    67.4
>TCONS_00006082    sp|P0DH62|Y4407_SELML    69.05    42    12    1    435    313    373    414    1e-08    60.1
>TCONS_00006082    sp|Q8RWZ5|SD25_ARATH    56.52    46    19    1    435    301    659    704    1e-08    60.1
>TCONS_00006082    sp|Q8VYA3|WAKLJ_ARATH    41.43    70    40    1    477    271    586    655    5e-08    58.2
>TCONS_00006082    sp|Q9C9L5|WAKLH_ARATH    40.00    70    41    1    477    271    600    669    5e-08    58.2
>TCONS_00006082    sp|P93749|Y2197_ARATH    40.54    74    43    2    501    283    225    297    6e-08    57.8
>TCONS_00006082    sp|Q9M342|WAKLP_ARATH    34.52    84    54    2    519    271    504    580    6e-08    57.8
```

Now, I want to filter those IDs with an e-value (field 11) > 0.001. How can I do this?

Comment: Given this is a Unix & Linux site, not a bioinformatics one, you might indicate which column is the "e value" (11?)...

Comment: ok sorry for the partial question. yes i know and its just simple filtering but i was in doubt about scientific expressions. and yes that is the 11th column

Comment: Please edit that information into your question: it removes unnecessary guesswork for people...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `awk`, I suppose that the 11th field is the value you mean:

```
awk '$11>0.001{print $0}' file
```

`awk` understands the scientific notation and prints the whole line, if the statement is true.

**Notice**: From the output in your question no line matches the criteria >0.001, so no line is printed. Instead you can test it as follows:

```
awk '$11>0.00000001{print $0}' file
```

4 lines should be printed.

Comment: The print is also unneeded, this will do just as well: `awk '$11>0.001' file`

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solution in perl ,

```
perl -lane 'print $_ if ($F[10] >0.001)' file
```

`-a` automatically splits each input line and stores the columns in an array `@F` and `$F[0]` will have the first column.